# Neural network classification loss from validation set: Does it update anything dynamically

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I'm attempting t study up a bit on the theory of training neural networks, and right now i have gotten to validation sets.

Now, I can understand that a validation set gives us a loss-index, which helps us in knowing whether we are overfitting or not. But when I read in books and and watch videos, everyone seems to express themselves in a manner that is a bit ambiguous.

Does the model update itself manually when the validation set is being run? can layers, weights, biases, or net-amounts of neurons be updated "automatically" when it is being validated?

Thank you very much

Comment: I believe you might want to look more into back-propagation. After the loss is calculated, the weights and biases are updated using a back-propagation algorithm to minimize loss. It is not common to change the number of neurons or the number of layers unless you are doing some sort of hyper-parameter optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Loss` and `Accuracy` refer to the current loss and accuracy of the training set.

The `Loss` is being fixed during back propagation of the epoch to improve the `Accuracy`.

At the end of each epoch your trained Neural Network is evaluated against your validation set. This is what `Validation Loss` and `Validation Accuracy` refer to.

Comment: yes but when i can read the loss after the end of an epoch, does that loss have any effect on the neural network, other than me reading the loss and adjusting the parameters?

Comment: Request you to go through this link-https://towardsdatascience.com/how-does-back-propagation-in-artificial-neural-networks-work-c7cad873ea7 that explains back propagation. After loss is calculated in forward propagation, the losses are fixed using optimization function in the backward propagation.

Comment: @s3j80 - If you are satisfied with the answer, can you please upvote and accept the answer. Thank You.